# Using ACCCEPTINVCHARS with a remote host

Tags: amazon-ec2, utf-8, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, amazon-redshift

I am using a scraper and uploading my data into redshift using EC2. I would prefer not to upload the data into S3 first. My code is in Jupyter Notebook. However, I get the "String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: 80 (error 3)" error that I see a lot of other people have asked about previously. I even found a page on redshift that walks through using a Remote Desktop. However, as I said before I would prefer not going through S3. Is this possible?
Currently using psycopg2 to connect to the database. I figured it wouldn't work but I tried just putting in acceptinvchars after the database user/password line, and it said that ACCEPTINVCHARS isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy data to Redshift right from your notebook you have to compose valid `INSERT` statements and execute them against the existing table in Redshift. However, throughput of this approach is quite low. I don't know how much data you plan to write but I guess scrappers should have higher throughput than that. You can first write the output of your Python script to the same EC2 instance and use `COPY` command.

More info on copying from an EC2 instance here: [COPY from Remote Host (SSH)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-ssh.html)

As for your error, you likely have accented letters in your input and you need to use `LATIN1` encoding everywhere

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know how I missed that one.